# Image alignment is not working properly when using layout_weight in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, imageview

I am going to design a dashboard of my application where couple of menus/buttons are present. Menus are indicated using some images. The menus are placed in 4 columns. First there columns are containing two menus each and fourth is containing three. The design of the screen is in the below image:

[image: dashboard image]

Now to develop this I have tried with Linearlayout and layout_weight. But I am not able to place them and the images are getting stretched. I have used the below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mumbaibg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="3" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/newcar" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/usedcar" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/carloan" />

         <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/service" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/sos" />

         <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/learndrive" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/insurance" />

         <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rtofinelist" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/newsoffer" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Images are getting placed on the each column but they are getting stretched. I have tried with .9patch image as well as placing the images are in different drawable folders.

With the current code, the screen is looking like this:

[image: screen with the current implementation]

Can any one give me a better and easy solution to achieve this.

Thanks,
Arindam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your scaling to work as expected, you need to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for horizontal layouts and `android:layout_height="0dp"` for vertical layouts.

Edit, here is a code sample that achieves the design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure what you tried, I edited my reply with sample code that I tested.

Answer (score 1):

Remove these two attributes in your layout:
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
They're responsible for the stretching.

You'll then hopefully have right aligned images.
Set layout_gravity to center and that should align the images into the middle of their corresponding grids.

Comment: I have applied this. But no luck.

Comment: What's happening? Still stretching?

Answer (score 1):

The parent LinearLayout that has direct children views needs to have `android:weightSum="3"` attribute specified. The child views already have the corresponding `android:layout_weight="1"` - so thats good. But the parent attribute is not present so the system doesnt know how to properly allocate the space for the child views.

Comment: I did not understand your view properly. So are you saying, I need to change android:weightSum="4" to android:weightSum="3"?